# Внедрение зависимостей. Как внедрять соединение с БД?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Есть приложение на ASP.NET Core наподобие [вот этого](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore). Используется подход CQRS. Обработчики запросов используют Dapper для чтения данных. В качестве DI контейнера используется SimpleInjector.

Вопрос следующий: как внедрять подключение к БД в обработчики запросов? Правильно ли регистрировать IDbConnection в контейнере? Как быть, если подключений должно быть несколько? Как освобождать соединения (dispose)? Должен ли обработчик запросов быть один на http-запрос (scoped) или создаваться при каждом запросе (transient)?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. как внедрять подключение к БД в обработчики запросов?

Абстрагировать работу с БД, закрыть её классом или интерфейсом, внедрять этот класс/интерфейс

> 2. Правильно ли регистрировать IDbConnection в контейнере?

Нет

> 3. Как быть, если подключений должно быть несколько?

Количеством подключений управляет пул подключений. Вам этим морочиться не нужно

> 4. Как освобождать соединения (dispose)?

Использовать [Dispose-паттерн](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern)

> 5. Должен ли обработчик запросов быть один на http-запрос (scoped) 
>          или создаваться при каждом запросе (transient)?

Если речь идет про контроллер или фильтр, то они обычно Scoped - то есть на каждый запрос создается новый экземпляр. Я за такой подход. Если речь идет про доступ к БД - тут я бы посоватовал делать отдельный экземпляр на транзакцию. Например, если в процессе запроса вам надо проверить роль юзера и также сохранить какие то полезные данные в БД в контроллере - ничего страшного не произойдет, если эти 2 операции будут произведены разными независимыми инстансами классов доступа к данным (а вот какие это будут подключения - одно и то же или разные - это головная боль пула подключений)